# Cant get action out of SystemTray in java

Tags: java

I am trying to open a website when someone clicks on a tray notification in java, however I can't seem to get my program to listen to them or I am missing something.

When I left click, nothing is put in console and image, name, and title are info I am getting from a twitchAPI call. I am trying to get test to post to console and going from there.

I am calling this in a class separate from the main class. GUI loads, and gets all live channels I follow making a "Channel" class for them. On the creation of the Channel class it runs this after it gets all info. I don't know if that might be the issue, but I don't see why it would be.

This is my code for the SystemTry

```
public void displayTray() throws AWTException, MalformedURLException {
    //Obtain only one instance of the SystemTray object
    SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

    //If the icon is a file
    Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(getLogo());
    //Alternative (if the icon is on the classpath):
    //Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(getClass().getResource("icon.png"));

    TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, name + " just went live!");
    //Let the system resize the image if needed
    trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
    //Set tooltip text for the tray icon
    trayIcon.setToolTip("System tray icon demo");
    tray.add(trayIcon);

    trayIcon.displayMessage(name + " just went live!", getTitle(), MessageType.INFO);

    //trayIcon.setActionCommand("LeftClick");
    trayIcon.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("test");
        }
    }); 


}
```

Hope someone can help me figure this out.

EDIT: I can confirm the program is creating the mouseListener by printing out getMouseLisnters()[0] and it giving me tests.TestGui$5@76f001db.

Comment: You should edit this up so it's a [MCVE] that is easier for other people to run and check and also describe the problem you're having  a bit more specifically and in detail - what you expected to happen, what actually happened, in what way were they different, etc.

Comment: Alright, I will try to this as much as I can. I am doing api calls with private things so not much will be able to be shared yet.

Comment: Imho, this code should work, strange.

Comment: I just tried your code. It works perfectly. So the issue isn't here

Comment: So I just need to figure out why mine won't print to console. Atleast I know its on my end.